# Get file name from path

Tags: c#

How do I get the folder name from my path?

This is the file path:

```
@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos"
```

Under the main path there's a folder that I want to get the name:

```
@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos\sample2"
@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos\sample3"
@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos\sample4"
```

Under the sample folder, there are videos that I want to get the name:

```
@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos\sample1\video1.mp4
```

This is my code:

```
foreach(string s in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos").Select(Path.GetFileName))
{
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Is this possible? How do I get the name of every file that exists inside my video/main folder using only the main path?

Comment: Did you google it?  I find it hard to believe that writing up this question was easier than searching for it in google.

Comment: sir im using only my main path to get all the file name

Comment: Why don't you just leave your loop be without using Linq, call `Path.GetFileName()` inside it and assign the result to a variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Videos", "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

foreach (string file in files)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

If you're trying to get the folder name from a full files path then do this

```
Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(file))
```

Comment: thank you sir this works but i want to get also the folder name inside my main path

Comment: Yes for your main path, just do Path.GetFileName

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx%20System.IO.Directory.GetFiles)

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
  "@"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\videos", 
  "*.mp4",
  System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```